# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' error occurred in anaconda 3, spyder

Tags: python

I am using anaconda with python 3.6 on win10. In spyder I run following code

```
import sklearn
```

but it shows following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

but I have installed sklearn

```
(C:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\David Tao\Documents>pip install sklearn  
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages  
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages   (from sklearn)
```

Someone know what is going on?

Answer (score -1):

Install sklearn with anaconda instead, which installs it by default in your current environment (I think by default pip will install in the system python)

```
conda install sklearn
```

or:

```
conda install -c <source> sklearn
```